# conversion MySQL DATE_FORMAT to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to convert MySQL DATE_FORMAT to POstgreSQL?

I have MySQL SQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_created), '%Y') AS year, 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_created) , '%m') AS month , 
COUNT(guid) AS total 
FROM ossn_users  
WHERE(time_created > 0) 
GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_created) ,  '%Y%m');
```

I convert it to :

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(time_created), 'YYYY') AS year,
to_char(to_timestamp(time_created) , 'MM') AS month,
COUNT(guid) AS total 
FROM ossn_users  
WHERE(time_created > 0) 
GROUP by to_char(to_timestamp(time_created),'YYYY'), to_char(to_timestamp(time_created),'MM')  ;
```

But it seems it does not work.

Please, what is right conversion?

Is this conversion right?

Thank you.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: I do not get right result and behavior of the application.

Comment: Can u provide database schema and dummy data?

Comment: The equivalent group by would be: `GROUP by to_char(to_timestamp(time_created),'YYYYMM')`

Comment: I tried and PostgreSQL gives me an error

Comment: what error? why not pupulating it in original post?..

Comment: Error was for GROUP by to_char(to_timestamp(time_created),'YYYYMM')